# Python: Repeated Measures ANOVA with multiple between-subjects factors

Tags: python, anova, mixed-models

I'm trying to run a mixed-model ANOVA to evaluate my dv for 1 within-subjects factor (time-point) and two between-subjects factors (Group and Sex).

As far as I can tell, there is no option for this in either statsmodels AnovaRM (between-subjects not implemented yet) or pingouin mixed_anova(can only use a single between-subjects factor). Is there any option at all for running this test in Python?